# Updating C++ Dll after deployment

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I created a c++ dll in Visual Studio 2010 and used it in another c++ console application to perform some basic math functions.I also created setup file containing the dll and the exe. However how do I update the dll after deploying the application in a client computer to add some extra functionality to my console application?

Comment: Making a new setup with the old application and new DLL is not doable?

Comment: I don't want to make a new setup. I just want to patch the new dll over the older one keeping the existing exe as it is.